# Edge animate: How to preload JSON information?

Tags: json, getjson, preload, stage, adobe-edge

I get the **JSON** info to the EdgeAnimate Stage (**creationComplete** Action) by this code:

```
$.getJSON('myJsonLink', function(data) {
});
```

**Problem**: the composition get's the info, after the animation starts. 
But the info needs to be loaded before animation.

it's very annoying problem for which I can't find the solution for days...
Can You help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getJSON` fires an *XMLHttpRequest* in an asynchronous mode, which means a request is sent, then we move on to the next iteration in the flow.

You may need to make your request synchronous instead, but unfortunatelly, `getJSON` does not support *synch* mode as far as I know so you should use the low-level `$.ajax()` method with the *async* property set to `false`:

```js
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: "myJsonLink",
  data: data,
  async: false,
  success: function () {}
});
```